# CSS `width: max-content` not working properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a image container which should resize itself according to the width of the image but it isn't resizing itself properly in Firefox, it works perfectly in chrome but in Firefox there is some space around the image, I have set the image's height to 100% to make it take up all the height of the container.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 899px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #303030;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #202020;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section-heading {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section-heading>h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.section-heading a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
}

.section-heading>a {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.section-heading a:hover {
  color: var(--theming);
}

.trending.card {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.cover-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
  background-color: red;
}

.cover-container:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.cover {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--same-background);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
}

.title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
}

.title a:hover {
  color: var(--theming);
}

.genres {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.genre {
  padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #404040;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.genre:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-background);
}

.genre:active {
  background-color: var(--lighter-background);
}

.trending.banner {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--same-background);
  position: absolute;
  align-self: flex-start;
  z-index: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
}

.trending.cover-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 40%;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.trending.manga.cover {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.trending.info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 71%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  gap: 0.1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.trending.title {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.trending.description {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.trending.actions {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.trending.action {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: var(--same-background);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.nav {
  width: 2.5rem !important;
}

.nav-icon {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-icon path {
  stroke: var(--secondary-color);
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}

.trending.action:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-background);
}

.trending.action:active {
  background-color: var(--lighter-background);
}
```

```html
<div class="trending container">
  <div class="trending section-heading">
    <h2><a href="#">Trending Now</a></h2>
    <a href="#">View All</a>
  </div>
  <div class="trending card" id="1">
    <div class="trending banner">
      <img src="https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/manga/banner/117195-VVYq1EEOwR0K.jpg" alt="" class="trending cover" loading="lazy" style="opacity: 1;">
    </div>
    <a href="/manga/117195" class="trending cover-container">
      <img src="https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/manga/cover/large/bx117195-r3kf8eF0xkDJ.png" alt="" class="trending manga cover" loading="lazy" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>
    <div class="trending info">
      <h3 class="trending title"><a href="/manga/117195">[Oshi no Ko]</a></h3>
      <div class="genres">

        <a href="/search/manga/Drama" class="trending genre">Drama</a>

        <a href="/search/manga/Mystery" class="trending genre">Mystery</a>

        <a href="/search/manga/Psychological" class="trending genre">Psychological</a>

        <a href="/search/manga/Supernatural" class="trending genre">Supernatural</a>

      </div>
      <p class="trending description">Gorou is a gynecologist and idol fan who’s in shock after his favorite star, Ai, announces an impromptu hiatus. Little does Gorou realize that he’s about to forge a bond with her that defies all common sense! Lies are an idol’s weapon! (Source:
        Yen Press)</p>
      <div class="trending actions">
        <a href="/manga/117195/read" class="trending action read">Read this Manga</a>
        <button class="trending action nav previous">
           <svg class="nav-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)">
             <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
             <g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g>
             <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
               <g id="Arrow / Arrow_Right_SM">
                 <path id="Vector" d="M7 12H17M17 12L13 8M17 12L13 16" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
               </g>
             </g>
           </svg>
         </button>
        <button class="trending action nav next">
           <svg class="nav-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
             <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
             <g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g>
             <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
               <g id="Arrow / Arrow_Right_SM">
                 <path id="Vector" d="M7 12H17M17 12L13 8M17 12L13 16" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
               </g>
             </g>
           </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code, and the `.trending.container` is supposed to take up the width of the inner image but it there is some extra space on left and right side of the image, this extra space is only visible in Firefox and the `.trending.container` is only as wide as image in chrome and works as I expected it to. Please help, thank you. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25qcawkv/11/show)

Answer (score 2):

### Workaround Summary

I found that applying `display: contents` on the surrounding anchor tag (`.trending.cover-container`) and then moving the important visual styles down to the image itself (`.trending.manga.cover`) seemed to resolve the issue in both Chrome and Firefox.

### Explanation

This extra spacing around the image is extremely difficult to remove, due to how percentage widths/heights work in CSS. Basically, when specifying a percentage height:

- The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block.

  - A "containing block" is identified by a parent block-level element *or* the nearest element that creates a new formatting context (e.g. flex or grid containers).
- If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, the value computes to `auto`.

[Source on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

Now, I'm no expert on browser implementations, but I would expect that the discrepancy arises from how Chrome vs Firefox interprets the word "explicitly." In messing around with your CSS, I found that if I applied enough hard-coded pixel dimensions in the hierarchy, the extra spacing would disappear on both Chrome and Firefox. But, of course, all of that hard-coding leads to unmaintainable stylesheets.

As an alternative, I found that applying `display: contents` as described above seemed to resolve the issue in a fairly unintrusive manner. See the snippet below. You can probably remove some more styles that have been made unnecessary by this change, but I only made the essential modifications.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 899px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #303030;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #202020;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section-heading {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section-heading>h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.section-heading a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
}

.section-heading>a {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.section-heading a:hover {
  color: var(--theming);
}

.trending.card {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.cover-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
  background-color: red;
}

.cover-container .cover:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.cover {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--same-background);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
}

.title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
}

.title a:hover {
  color: var(--theming);
}

.genres {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.genre {
  padding: 0.1rem 0.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #404040;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.genre:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-background);
}

.genre:active {
  background-color: var(--lighter-background);
}

.trending.banner {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--same-background);
  position: absolute;
  align-self: flex-start;
  z-index: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
}

.trending.cover-container {
  display: contents;
  height: 100%;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 40%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.trending.manga.cover {
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.trending.info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 71%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  gap: 0.1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.trending.title {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.trending.description {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.trending.actions {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.trending.action {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: var(--same-background);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.1s all linear;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.nav {
  width: 2.5rem !important;
}

.nav-icon {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-icon path {
  stroke: var(--secondary-color);
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}

.trending.action:hover {
  background-color: var(--primary-background);
}

.trending.action:active {
  background-color: var(--lighter-background);
}
```

```html
<div class="trending container">
  <div class="trending section-heading">
    <h2><a href="#">Trending Now</a></h2>
    <a href="#">View All</a>
  </div>
  <div class="trending card" id="1">
    <div class="trending banner">
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/1500x500" alt="" class="trending cover" loading="lazy" style="opacity: 1;">
    </div>
    <a href="/manga/117195" class="trending cover-container">
      <img src="//dummyimage.com/300x450" alt="" class="trending manga cover" loading="lazy" style="opacity: 1;">
    </a>
    <div class="trending info">
      <h3 class="trending title"><a href="/manga/117195">[Oshi no Ko]</a></h3>
      <div class="genres">

        <a href="/search/manga/Drama" class="trending genre">Drama</a>

        <a href="/search/manga/Mystery" class="trending genre">Mystery</a>

        <a href="/search/manga/Psychological" class="trending genre">Psychological</a>

        <a href="/search/manga/Supernatural" class="trending genre">Supernatural</a>

      </div>
      <p class="trending description">Gorou is a gynecologist and idol fan who’s in shock after his favorite star, Ai, announces an impromptu hiatus. Little does Gorou realize that he’s about to forge a bond with her that defies all common sense! Lies are an idol’s weapon! (Source:
        Yen Press)</p>
      <div class="trending actions">
        <a href="/manga/117195/read" class="trending action read">Read this Manga</a>
        <button class="trending action nav previous">
           <svg class="nav-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)">
             <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
             <g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g>
             <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
               <g id="Arrow / Arrow_Right_SM">
                 <path id="Vector" d="M7 12H17M17 12L13 8M17 12L13 16" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
               </g>
             </g>
           </svg>
         </button>
        <button class="trending action nav next">
           <svg class="nav-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
             <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
             <g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g>
             <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
               <g id="Arrow / Arrow_Right_SM">
                 <path id="Vector" d="M7 12H17M17 12L13 8M17 12L13 16" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
               </g>
             </g>
           </svg>
         </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **I still think the root issue is unresolved**, i.e. the discrepancy between Firefox and Chrome (what is being interpreted ambiguously, which browser is "correct," and what user-level workarounds exist if any). I'll continue following this Q/A in hope that someone with more expertise than myself can provide insight!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this did solve the issue for me but as you said, the root issue still remains, nonetheless, Thanks a lot for your help!!